Running Docker in windows, Error with creating container of server
This is the error what I get, and Don't know what to do with files or config, Using Docker on windows
using command docker-compose up --build

Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tried to run the project and use container but was unable to

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
